# Minimum cost problem with additional constraints

Tags: algorithm

The problem I'm trying to solve:

I've sent a list of products to suppliers, each supplier returns a list of their prices. Based on this I need to work out where to buy each item, bearing in mind that the supplier's shipping cost is a one off. Meaning that it's not always cost effective to go to the cheapest supplier if that's the only item we're buying from them.

I've looked into Linear Programming to solve this but it seems to rely on the fact that pricing is constant. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How efficient does it have to be, a brute force solution isnt too hard to come up with

Comment: It's not hard but it's certainly very slow. One would brute-force the subset of suppliers and the subset of products from each supplier in the subset.

Comment: @Daniel how I would do it is for each item you have |Suppliers| choices about where to purchase it, try every option. It would be O(|Suppliers|^|Products|) but for small enough inputs which may be good enough for the real world it could work

Comment: You could also add some pruning techniques to shorten it quite a bit

Comment: It isn't clear you need any kind of optimization here.  The simple case (ex shipping) boils down to a row for each supplier and columns for each product.  Absent other constraints, you buy from the supplier with the cheapest prooduct price (column MIN).  How large is your list of products/suppliers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach to solve this problem.

Let's break this down into subproblems, where the solution to each subproblem `(p, s)` is the cost of buying products `0` through `p` from suppliers `0` through `s`, along with the list of suppliers to buy from. Here is the algorithm:

```
memo = {}
# example memo entry: memo[3, 4] = 50, [a, b, c] means the 3 products cost 50, and the first is bought
# at supplier number a, the second at b, etc (out of 4 possible suppliers)

for s in range(0, len(suppliers)):
    for p in range(0, len(products)):
        # first we have some base cases
        if p == 0 and s == 0:
             # one product, one supplier
             memo[p, s] = cost(suppliers[s], products[p]), [s]
        elif p == 0:
             # one product, from any supplier
             old_cost, old_list = memo[p, s-1]
             new_cost = cost(suppliers[s], products[p]) + shipping(suppliers[s])
             if new_cost < old_cost:
                 memo[p, s] = new_cost, [s]
             else:
                 memo[p, s] = old_cost, old_list
        elif s == 0:
             # multiple products, one supplier
             cost, old_list = memo[p-1, s]
             cost += cost(suppliers[s], products[p])
             memo[p, s] = cost, old_list + [s]
        else:
            # cost of using the first s-1 suppliers for the first p-1 products
            new_cost, new_sublist = memo[p-1, s-1]
            # add the cost of buying current product (p) at current supplier (s)
            new_cost += cost(suppliers[s], products[p])
            # calculate new shipping costs as well
            if s not in new_sublist:
                # s is a new supplier that we weren't using before, so add shipping
                new_cost += shipping(suppliers[s])
            # add new supplier to list
            new_sublist += [s]
            # now calculate other option, where we don't use this supplier for this product
            old_cost, old_sublist = memo[p, s-1]
            if new_cost < old_cost:
                result = new_cost, new_sublist
            else:
                result = old_cost, old_sublist
            memo[p, s] = result
```

The final result is `memo[P, S]` (where S is the number of suppliers and P is the number of product types). The runtime of this algorithm is O(S*P)

Comment: Edited to clarify your overall approach.

Comment: Thanks for the well written explanation. I have one issue with the algorithm, when we compare the difference of buying the product p from supplier s against supplier s-1. We also need to compare the cost of buying products 0...p-1 from supplier s against supplier s-1. Unless I've misunderstood something @einpoklum

Comment: Since you are iterating through every product, you have already analyzed buying 0...p-1 from s or s-1. When you buy product p, you add the best score of buying 0...p-1 from 0...s-1 to buying p from s, and you compare to buying all of 0....p from 0...s-1